# Why are 2 for loops needed in this program?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Why does this program need 2 for loops to function? Is there a way to write this without the 2 for loops?

Its purpose is to assign integer values 1-25 to an array with a length of 25. It then prints the array as five separate lines each containing five array elements separated by commas.

Its output is this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25
```

```
public class ArrayNums
{
     static int[] arrayList = new int[25];

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

        for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
           arrayList[i] = i + 1;   
        printArray();
     }

     public static void printArray()

     {
        int i;
        for(i=1; i<=25; i++){
            if (i % 5 != 0)
                System.out.print(arrayList[i-1]+",");
            else
                System.out.println(arrayList[i-1]);
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Just remove `arrayList` and print `i` directly.

Comment: arrayList is a misleading name for an Array...

Comment: What do you have against using loops? This code is simple enough that you don't need to over optimize it

Comment: @cricket_007 Nothing against loops. I am very new to Java and just don't understand how these 2 loops interact with each other.

Comment: The first loop builds the array. The second loops over the elements of the array and prints them. You can certainly combine them into one, but it's more preferred in certain cases to have `buildArray()` as a separate function from `printArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the main function would go like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
       arrayList[i] = i + 1;   
       if ((i+1) % 5 != 0)
            System.out.print(arrayList[i]+",");
        else
            System.out.println(arrayList[i]);
    }
}
```

Though, it's considered better practice to have one function doing only one thing at a time. It makes it much easier to understand, hence your first version I would rather advice to use.

Comment: Thank you. You code above just outputs "25" and not the list.

Comment: @HerdingDogRescuer You probably forgot the `{` after the `for` loop or inserted a `;` before the `{`

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I did have a curly brace misplaced. Thank you.

Comment: @vee_ess Noted and thank you. Just exploring options and learning why the code works like it does.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it separate because this enables **Separation of Concerns** and better usage and maintenance of the program. As @cricket_007 stated, it's better to "have buildArray() as a separate function from printArray()".

In this scenario, the output *could* be achieved using a single loop and you *could* print i instead of the arrayList contents, but I doubt you really have a critical need to print 1 to 25 on 5 lines - assume the build and print functions would change in practice. Consider a few scenarios:

**Scenario 1**
Let's say the program was later required to also output to a CSV file and return a JSON object (not at the same time but by different function calls). If you're building and printing in the same loop, now you need to put the building part into three different functions.

**Scenario 2**
Let's say you need to change the contents of the array from numbers to letters or inputted data or the ability for the program to do any of those three. Making this change within the loop makes it harder to see potential conflicts or errors.

**Scenario 3**
Both Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.`You could easily add the printarray() method inside the first method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1;i<=25;i++){
        arrayList[i-1]=i;
        if(i%5==0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }else{
            System.out.print(i+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +Erangad Thank you. I am not clear about adding the printArray() method. When I try to I get the following error: moreArray.java:5: error: cannot find symbol